# Should not allow other resources to be accessed

Tags: web-applications, zk

I have following ZUL files in my web content folder

```
Login.zul - Composer Applied
Category.zul - No Composer Applied 
Index.zul - Composer Applied
Help.zul - NO Composer Applied
AboutUs.zul - NO Composer Applied
```

whenever I try to access Category.zul or Help.zul I can see them in my browser, but according to my usecase If I try to access it, I should always be redirected to Login.zul How can I achieve this.

One Solution : I can add composer to all the ZUL and then in doAfterCompose() do Executions.sendRedirect("to my login page") , but I think this not correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented [DestopInit](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/util/DesktopInit.html) Interface, of ZK when ever new desktop is initialized i.e when I open link in new tab. I have checked Page URL if it is not Login I have redirected user back to Login Page.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few standard ways to handle this

1. Use [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) or [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) to define secured resources
2. Put all restricted pages under WEB-INF and dynamically include them when requested from your application UI
3. Implement a custom authentication and authorization system to decide which user has access to what (something like the approach you have already mentioned in your question). Personally I would  recommend using a standard security solution like Shiro or Spring Security. For integrating Shiro into your ZK application see this [smalltalk](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2012/March/Securing_ZK_Applications_With_Apache_Shiro). For Spring Security you can refer to ZK Spring Essentials section on [Working with Spring Security](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Spring%20Essentials/Working%20with%20ZK%20Spring/Working%20with%20ZK%20Spring%20Security)

Comment: Note in your answer that they are used separately.